# Configure Exchange ActiveSync Mailbox Policy to Enable Samsung Galaxy S5 Fingerprint Sensor

Tags: exchange, activesync

I just got the first Samsung Galaxy S5 in our Exchange 2010 organization (I also happen to be the Exchange admin).  I'd like to use the S5's fingerprint sensor to unlock the phone, but it appears the Exchange Server's ActiveSync mailbox policy is preventing this and I've not successfully determined what setting must be changed to enable the fingerprint sensor.  Googling the problem seems to suggest this is a problem with the phone but I found no solutions that didn't involve buying a new e-mail app.

I'm using the stock e-mail app on the phone and would like to continue to do so.  I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve disabling enforcing a password requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it's the passcode policy. Is this active?

Comment: Yes, the 'Require password' policy is active.  Even with this policy set but no further settings specified, the Fingerprint Swipe unlock method is disabled.  However, as I indicated in my original post, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't disable some sort of password...lest users not enable fingerprint and instead use NO lock method.

Comment: This is not possible. Exchange/ActiveSync do not distinguish this. Passcode is Passcode, and they have no clue about "swipe"

Comment: For some reason, the new iPhone 6 allows the fingerprint but only after you set the EAS pin. Not sure what the difference is with the Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further research and trial-and-error troubleshooting has confirmed that, if as stated in my question the solution must not result in using a non-stock e-mail app on the Galaxy S5 phone, it's not possible to use the fingerprint scanner without disabling the password requirement on the Exchange Server.  **So the answer is, "it can't be done"** (without using a different e-mail app).

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution if you are ready to use cloudmagic email app. Link is here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudmagic.mail

Happy finger print :P